# What type of queue is TCP accept queue in Linux -- FIFO/LIFO/other?

Tags: linux-kernel, tcp

I am wondering if TCP accept queue in Linux is a FIFO or LIFO, or any other type of queue?

Asking the same from another perspective: does `accept()` yield connections in the same order as they arrived to the host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

citing `man 2 accept`:

> It extracts the first connection request on the queue of pending connections

so, FIFO principle. ["Queue" actually says that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)); the word always refers to a FIFO data structure (just as the queue in your post office, where you need to have been the first there to be served first).

> connections in the same order as they arrived to the host?

Connections do not "arrive"! That's the problematic thing in this formulation, and where ambiguity actually comes from.

Let's have a look at a simplified [view of the TCP state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol):

[image: simplified TCP state machine]
<sup>Author: Skil100, [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Tcp_state_diagram_fixed_new.svg), CC-BY-SA 3.0</sup>

Now, it's not intuitively clear who should be "first" in the queue: the first one whose SYN was received? The first one to which a SYN-ACK could be sent to? Or the first one whose ACK to that was received?

But thinking about it, the point where the kernel knows a socket is ready for `accept` returning something is when it receives the `ACK`.
So, that's the order by which things are inserted into the accept queue.

However, note that this is highly stochastic: it depends on how fast both ends react to SYN, SYN-ACK packets, and how long it takes to transport these.

**You generally mustn't assume that the first entry in the accept queue is the first client to initiate a connection.** That has bitten many network protocol designers in the past, in cases where you need for multiple parties to connect to relay messages (you literally can't know whether you need to store a message for a later connected node; you will have to have logic on top of everything to avoid the *late joiner* problem).

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63345712/4433386) is an all-time classic and probably has more internals than you want to know.

Comment: In last paragraph you actually answered my real concern. Our problem is that we observe that health check connections to our service seems to stash, and causes monitoring system to reboot the service (Kubernetes) or disconnect backend server (HAProxy).

Comment: yeah, but then the question is why you're expecting health check connections to happen in any specific order. They need to happen within a specific time frame, that's it?

Comment: Yes. Timeframe is essential. Nevertheless, healtcheck in HAproxy is done each 2 senconds. Let's assume HAproxy has configured 10 slots for incomming connections. Our service has 11 slots/workers (to have space for health checks). And we see such moments that there are "real" connections arriving ("real" meaning non-healthcheck, during 30-40 seconds or even more), and then, bunch of health checks are handled in a row. Maybe problem is somewhere in HAproxy, so I wanted to clarify how it looks from a backend server/kernel perspective.

Comment: I fail to see how anything below a thousand TCP connections per second should be any problem for a modern computer running linux; this is **very** likely an application level problem. Also, I don't know HAProxy, but why would you make a new TCP connection every 2s? That seems very inelegant.

Comment: Me neither, thus searching for a root cause(s). I do not exclude application errors (we seems to have strange code for epolling a shared socket/accepting). For the latter, I do not know the answer. It is the inherited state. 2s is default for HAProxy, so maybe someone just "done and forgot".